# Triplet Loss not reducing

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

My triplets are defined as follows: -

```
for i, (inputs, poses) in enumerate(train_loader):

        inputs = inputs.to(device)  # anchor - batch of images
        positives = positive_tfs(inputs)  # same batch with many augmentations
        shuffle_indices = torch.randperm(config.batch_size)
        negatives = inputs[shuffle_indices]  # same batch but shuffled

        inputs = torch.cat([inputs, positives, negatives])
        vlad_embeddings, pos_out, ori_out = model(inputs)
        a_vlad, p_vlad, n_vlad = torch.split(vlad_embeddings, config.batch_size)
```

I'm using loss provided by PyTorch

```
triplet_loss = nn.TripletMarginLoss(margin=1.0, p=2)
triplet_loss = triplet_loss(a_vlad, p_vlad, n_vlad)
```

However the loss ranges from 1.0 to 0.8 and doesn't seem to decrease below that. Any help would be appreciated! I've included my model code in the comments.

Comment: Model for NetVLAD courtesy of https://github.com/lyakaap/NetVLAD-pytorch/blob/master/netvlad.py